# How do I get Windows 7 to remember what I typed in the "File name" box of the Open File dialog?

Tags: windows-7

I just noticed this relatively small but annoying quirk about Windows 7 that wasn't present in Windows XP. In XP, whenever I was in the generic "Open File" dialog that almost every application shares, I was able to type `..` in the "File name" box, press enter to go up a level, and then just continue hitting Enter to continue moving up levels, because each time the `..` I typed would remain there in the box.

[image: Windows XP Open File Dialog]

But now that I'm using Windows 7, I quickly realized that after I type `..` and press Enter, it clears whatever I typed, thereby requiring me to re-type the `..` each time rather than being able to press Enter repeatedly to navigate further upward. Is there any way to configure Windows 7 to behave more like XP in this regard? It's just kind of annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shortcut for up folder is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd>.

Comment: That's not *directly* answering the question, but it does effectively the same thing so I'm marking it as the answer. Thanks!